Catastrophic cancellation
Catastrophic cancellation becomes of concern when calculating long dot products. It seems that the best way to avoid this could be a block floating point implementation, where the accumulator is designed to meet the length of the input vectors. Example - for 1,000,000 long vectors the quantization error could propagate to the 5th bit of the mantissa in 32-bit FP.
What other techniques are suggested to cope with this deficiency of FP?
